# Is there a better way to do Multiple OR Condition IIF Statement with Access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a IIf statement calculated field in my access query using multiple `OR` conditions checking against the same column.

Is there a better way than what I have below I know as this list grows I would like to not have to continue creating an ever growing line.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
IIF (field1 = "NAME 1" OR field1 = "NAME 2" OR field1 = "NAME 3" 
OR field1 = "NAME 4" OR field1 = "NAME 5" 
OR ... Continue to all names added, "True", "False")
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do a simple `IN` statement:

```
IIF (field1 IN("NAME 1", "NAME 2", "NAME 3", "NAME 4","NAME 5"), "True", "False")
```

Alternatively, you can create a table with allowed names, and test if field1 is in that table:

```
IIF (Exists(SELECT 1 FROM TableNames WHERE Field1 = TableNames.Name), "True", "False")
```

I recommend the second approach, if you have a long list of things you want to use in multiple places, you should store it in a table, and not copy-paste it around.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance